# c# UI automation StructureChanged Event Handler slow

Tags: c#, user-interface, ui-automation

I'm working with the C# UI automation library and trying to attach an event handler to the window im watching to see when the structure changes. I am currently having a problem of preformance, as it takes around 1.5 seconds to trigger the event. The code I am using is as follows:

```
AutomationElement window = AutomationElement.FromHandle(processes[0].MainWindowHandle); 
Automation.AddStructureChangedEventHandler(window, TreeScope.Children, new StructureChangedEventHandler(OnStructureChanged));
```

I am guessing that the TreeScope.Children is taking a while to walk through to trigger the event? If so or if not, what would be the best way to make this event trigger faster?